# Virtual host, apache2 and aws no access

Tags: php, apache, magento, ubuntu, amazon-web-services

Created a instance in aws with ubuntu 14:04 server, installed and configured my apache2 virtual hosts as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName magento.com
    ServerAlias www.magento.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/magento.com/public_html

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/magento.com/public_html>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
<VirtualHost>
```

and

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName recomendador.com
    ServerAlias www.recomendador.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/recomendador.com/public_html

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/recomendador.com/public_html>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
<VirtualHost>
```

My files are in:

```
/var/www/magento.com/public_html/
/var/www/recomendador.com/public_html/
```

My /etc/hosts :

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 magento.com
127.0.0.1 recomendador.com
```

When I access my aws:

```
http://meu_ip/
```

Opens magento, when I access:

```
http://meu_ip/recomendador.com
```

or

```
http://meu_ip/www.recomendador.com
```

Appears was not found on this server.

If I type:

```
http://meu_ip/magento.com
```

or

```
http://meu_ip/www.magento.com
```

That is, it seems he only recognizes the magento and still no use ServerName or ServerAlias.

I enabled both the a2ensite

Anyone know what might be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry if I misunderstood the question, but shouldn't you be calling http://mangento.com and http://recomendador.com directly? (also, you should set your own local /etc/hosts to the aws IP for the two domains)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so if I call within the server itself I created on amazon and works directly accessing magento.com recomendador.com, only not for external access, or from my computer to the server amazon i access like this: 

http://ip_servidor_amazon/ 

Ai apache2 calls magento.com only I can not call the recomendador.com, so I tried for example: 

http://ip_servidor_amazon/recomendador.com 

and does not work, do not know if I could explain better now.